# Find the stock exchanges a security is traded in given a CIK?

Tags: market-data, sec

I have all the CIKs and relative tickers of all the traded securities that I need (https://www.sec.gov/include/ticker.txt).

My question is: **How do I find the stock exchange that a gives security is traded in, given any CIK?** (I am looking for an official data source for this, possibly the sec.gov website)

I found some other unofficial sources which I could use, like those:
(http://oatsreportable.finra.org/OATSReportableSecurities-SOD.txt)
(https://rapidapi.com/logicione/api/stock-ticker-security-and-company-search-database) (https://sec.report/CIK)

But I don't know where do they get their data from, and it does not always correspond to the data I get from the SEC website, so I would like to find some "official" data, possibly from the sec.gov website.

Comment: You may indeed find this on sec.gov.  Just look through the company's SEC filings.  The info you seek is there--in the S-1 initially.  If a company switches exchanges other filings will contain that info.

Comment: Another 'unverified' source is ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory/ namely the ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory/nasdaqtraded.txt file